# Is there any sophisticated role-playing game framework available?

Tags: frameworks, game-engine

I'm looking for a role-playing game framework which fulfills the following critera:

- Open source / Free for non-commercial
- Targeted language doesn't matter as long as it's not too obscure (C# or Java would be great)
- The framework doesn't have to provide any graphics, sounds or other "low level" stuff
- The framework should support complex, non-linear story lines (like Fallout 1/2/3)
- The character should be highly configurable (again like Fallout or Dragon Age)
- Support for a party would be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [GemRB](http://www.gemrb.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start), a port of the Infinity Engine (i.e. Baldur's Gate). It's licensed under the GPL and written in C++ and Python if I'm not mistaken. Since it's based on the Infinity Engine, I would assume that all of the last three requirements apply as well.