# designing class hierarchy for typical characters in role playing game

Tags: c#

I'm trying to design a simple role playing game which has your typical character types like fighter, wizard, cleric, thief, etc. I need advice on a good way to setup the class hierarchy.

My initial attempt was to create a class of type "Character" and make the fighter, wizard, cleric, derived types from "Character".

But then I thought it might be better to create a "Character" class and then use the decorator pattern. So say a fighter decorator, wizard decorator, etc.

Or is there a different way that would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a combination of strategy and decorator pattern. Your initial suggestion is something like a strategy pattern approach.

Try to distinguish between character types and character traits. Character types would be something like fighter, wizard, cleric, … and design it with a strategy pattern, which result to some hierarchy tree.

Character traits would be elements like fire elemental, water elemental, black force, …

E.g. a fighter character might choose between fire and water elemental to be his native origin, like a pirate (aarrrr!) or a blacksmith. If you design this hierarchically, then you are doomed, because this will let your hierarchy tree explode in size.

Such character traits should be rather implemented with the decorator pattern, because it’s an orthogonal concept to the character concept. So you’ll basically create a fighter character and wrap a water elemental decorator around to get a pirate (aarrrr!). Or create a wizard character and wrap a dark magic decorator around him to get a dark mage. Or: Crate a wizard character and wrap a water elemental and a dark magic decorator around him to get a swampland wizard.

Some food for thoughts:

- If you decide to have all character
  have magic abilities, then design
  magic as character trait.
- If necessary: Organize
  the decorators in some kind of
  hierarchical structure. You might
  have an "elemental" (water, fire,
  earth, wind) decorator hierarchy and
  "magic type" (black, white) decorator
  hierarchy.

Have fun!

Comment: this comment best answers my actual question. but thanks @Jason D for the great advice

Answer (score 7):

**I think you may be putting the cart before the horse on this one.**

Your first order of business shouldn't be determining "How do I represent a character?"  It should be determining "what is it I want to represent?" That is to say: A tool to help with d20 character creation, Shadowrun, Mongoose Traveller, GURPS character creation, WH : Dark Heresy Character Creation; "My own cool d20 based RPG video game", A character and adventure/party management suite of software for sale,...etc. *Define this in implementation neutral terms.*

After you've successfully determined what it is you want to make, create a detailed definition of what it is you want to make.  One way of doing this is to list all the major nouns and verbs (Character, Wizard, Fighter, Create, Save, Delete, Copy....etc) and begin understanding the relationships among the various concepts you'll need to represent.  Then take each major noun and decompose it into its constituent parts. (Character: <s>can be a class</s> can be one or more classes, has some equipment,<s>has a Strength</s>, <s>has Hit Points, has Magic Points</s>, has some Primary and Secondary Attributes.)  Continue this decomposition until you're not able to use implementation neutral terms (e.g integer...etc).

Then look back at your definitions and decompositions and determine if there are any obvious contradictory statements, if so, get rid of the contradiction.  If not, then organize the data by the described hierarchy.  In my example, it could be appropriate to have Character, Class, Equipment and Primary Attribute as classes.

Be sure to keep all these "facts" organized and making their relationships clear, both in writing and diagramming. From there you should be able to begin considering implementation specifics such as a class hierarchy where wizard derives from character...etc.

You may also want to see how others have implemented things look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717340/is-there-any-sophisticated-role-playing-game-framework-available) for a link to an video game engine that implements a d20. (i.e. Baldurs Gate)

Comment: Thanks Diadistis.  I'm actually making my own pen and paper RPG at the moment so I've had to consider the OPs questions and more.  To assist with this I'm also writing software. :-)  I find it amazing at how quickly this particular concept can become complex.  Keeping it simple is an ongoing challenge for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go along with your initial attempt, creating a Character class and then extending the functionality through inheritance. Though all characters will do the same actions (use an item, attack, use a skill), the results will differ (method overloading, i.e.). I think it'd be clearer to use this model, I'm not sure about decorators.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that can be answered on a theoretical and practical level. For theory, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle .

But I think you are interested in practice. In that case, ask yourself, "is a wizard a character", i.e. can you do all the things you can do with a wizard with a generic character? If so, then go ahead and inherit. This will let you use more abstract code with a Character type rather than the specific instance. The decorator is more useful when you want to compose a subset of possible extensions in a variety of ways, i.e. if in your case a character could be simultaneously a cleric, a wizard, or a cleric and something else, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how flexible you want your RPG character engine to be. If you subclass your character class then you limit your character diversification to the compile time. If you however use design patterns like the decorator or behavior pattern you can also create character classes at runtime by combining decorators or behavior objects. (Although you wouldn't use a "wizard" decorator but a "magic" decorator to create a wizard, an elf, etc. Decorators are made to be reused, that is their strength.)

It really depends on what you want to learn, fundamental class design (characters by subclass) or modern object oriented design (characters by composition). If you are an absolute beginner at this go with the first method to get to know the principles. If you already know these principles you should grab yourself a good book on [design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read) and apply them to your game.