# Abstract class and interfaces in java

Tags: java

Any body can tell me

when to use the abstract class and when to use interface?

So many websites having only differences. I am not able to get these terms

"when to use the abstract class and when to use interface"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of Java \[Interfaces / Abstract classes\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869222/use-of-java-interfaces-abstract-classes)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces cannot contain implementation (at least prior to Java 8) so if you need "common" method implementation, you have to have it in a super class (be it abstract or concrete)

However, any class can have only one super class (but many interfaces). so an interface is the solution for polymorphism when you have a class that already got a super class

Comment: Does your answer anyhow reflects when to use interface/abstract class and when not to. You just give the definition of that  :-O !!!

Comment: @Altius: when to use super class: "if you need "common" method implementation", when to use interface: "when you have a class that already got a super class"

Comment: I got your point but your answer certainly doesn't reflect that I think you need to modify and elaborate your answer

Comment: what do you mean "your answer certainly doesn't reflect that". I was qouting my answer. it is possible that it can benefit from elaboration, but it DOES answer the question (even better than the longer other answer, imo) and i think the downvote is uncalled for.

Answer (score 1):

**Interfaces**

An interface is kinda* like a template. Say for example that you want to make a 'Shape' class. Not all shapes use the same formulas for calculating area, so you just establish that there has to be a "getArea" method, but you don't define it.

A simple example:

```
public interface Shape
{

    public int getArea();

}
```

Then you can have a class that implements the Shape interface:

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape
{
    //this works for rectangles but not for circles or triangles
    public int getArea()
    {
       return this.getLength() * this.getHeight();
    }

}
```

**Abstract Classes**

Abstract methods can be extended by subclasses.* They differ from interfaces in that they can also contain defined methods.

You can still leave undefined methods, but you must label them abstract.

An example:

```
public abstract class Vegetable 
{
    public String vegName;
    public boolean edible = true;

    public Vegetable(final String vegName, final boolean edible)
    {
        this.vegName = vegName;
        this.edible = edible;
    }

    public void printName()
    {
        System.out.println(this.vegName);
    }

    //to be determined later when implemented
    public abstract void drawOnScreen();
```

}

Then we can extend this abstract class.

```
public class Carrot extends Vegetable
{
    //we must define the abstract methods
    public void drawOnScreen()
    {
        //we can still use our other methods
        this.printName();

        //do some other thing that is specific to this class
    }
}
```

Comment: "Abstract methods ... can be used to extend a class" should be   Abstract methods can be extended by subclasses

Comment: interfaces can have members

Comment: this answer also defines the differences instead of "when to use"